# (com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201705301746) requires 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core 5.2.0' but it could not be found

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle, eclipse-oxygen

I am setting up eclipse after installing it. I do Window -> Preferences -> Maven - > Discovery-> Open Catalog and I select m2e-checkstyle and I try to install it. It throws the below error. I am using eclipse oxygen on linux box.

```
Operation details
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse 1.0.0.201705301746 (com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201705301746)
Missing requirement: Checkstyle configuration plugin for M2Eclipse 1.0.0.201705301746 (com.basistech.m2e.code.quality.checkstyle.feature.feature.group 1.0.0.201705301746) requires 'net.sf.eclipsecs.core 5.2.0' but it could not be found
```

Comment: You probably have to install the main Checkstyle plugins first. The `net.sf.eclipsecs.core` plugin it is looking for is part of the main Checkstyle install.

Comment: I get this when I try installing checkstyle plugin from market place.

Comment: Unable to read repository at https://checkstyle.org/eclipse-cs/update/content.xml.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999593/eclipse-plugin-checkstyle. That was never answered either. Does the following issue help you? https://github.com/checkstyle/eclipse-cs/issues/86

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late to answer this, but here's how I got it fixed -

1. In eclipse, open the marketplace window,
2. In search tab, search for "checkstyle" (without the quotes)
3. Install "Checkstyle Plug-in" from search results
4. Try installing the plugin which failed to install earlier (The one that made you read this)